# What is Solidity's equivalent of raw_call()?

Tags: solidity, calldata, vyper, function

I'm wondering, does Solidity also have a raw_call() function like Vyper which sends a byte[] array (payload) as calldata to a specific address?

If so, what is that function? Is it also raw_call()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.19/units-and-global-variables.html):

> ***<address>.call(bytes memory) returns (bool, bytes memory)***
>
> Issue low-level CALL with the given payload, returns success condition and return data, forwards all available gas, adjustable

The `call` function is available on the address primitive and it allows you to call an address with an arbitrary payload